# Require an expression to be formatted as an exponential expression

Tags: output-formatting, expression-manipulation

How can I require Mathematica to format an expression like
`Exp[x] x^s` as `Exp[x + s Log[x]]`?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful. (You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers)

Comment: I would just do it manually: `expr = Exp[x] x^s; Assuming[
 x > 0 && s > 0, (Exp@*FullSimplify@*Log)[expr]]`.

Comment: `Exp[z]` automatically evaluates to `Power[E, z]`, so I don't think there is.  There is a way to format output in the way you indicate, but the internal representation willl revert to `Power`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
Exp[x] x^s /. {a_^b_ :> Exp[log[a] b]} /. log -> Log // InputForm
```

returns the result

```
E^(x + s*Log[x])
```

which is what I think you wanted. By comparison, the original expression

```
Exp[x] x^s // InputForm
```

returns the result

```
E^x*x^s
```

Answer (score 1):

Method for output formatting:

```
MakeBoxes[Power[b_, p_], form_] := 
 With[{p2 = p*Log[b]}, MakeBoxes[Exp[p2], form]];
MakeBoxes[Times[pow__Power, c__], form_] := MakeBoxes[Times[c, Times[pow]]];
MakeBoxes[Times[pow__Power], form_] := 
 With[{p2 = 
    With[{terms = List @@@ {pow}}, 
     Total[terms[[All, 2]] Log[terms[[All, 1]]]]]}, 
  MakeBoxes[Exp[p2], form]]

Exp[x] x^s
(*  Exp[x + s Log[x]]  *)

2 + y Exp[x] x^s
(*  2 + y Exp[x + s Log[x]]  *)
```

I don't know if this is desired, but it shows that all powers are converted to `Exp[]`:

```
x^2
(*  Exp[2 Log[x]]  *)
```